# Specific difference between \math<xx> and \text<xx> in math mode

Tags: math-mode, bold, sans-serif, roman, mathtime

In the process of moving almost entirely to OpenType fonts for text and math, but trying to retain MathTime Pro II as the math font, I am realizing that some of these commands may not actually do what I thought they did.  In math mode, both `\mathbf` and `\textbf` pull upright boldface characters from the selected text font.  I had believed that `\mathbf` was getting characters from `mtpro2`, but that actually requires one to use `\mbf`.  The characters in `mtpro2` have slightly increased side-spacing as explained in the manual `guide2.pdf` available from the website.  So what are the differences between `\mathbf` and `\textbf` (or, for that matter, `\mathrm` and `\textrm`, `\mathsf` and `\textsf`, etc.) when used in math mode?  Is this to give you the option of having two different fonts available for each family, series, shape, etc. in math mode (to deal with the spacing issue perhaps)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\mathbf` will give the bold upright font declared for math or with `unicode-math` package optionally is an alias for `\symbf` which selects the bold math alphabet and is not a font change.

`\textbf` switches to text mode from math mode and selects whatever font is declared as bold for the text current outside the current math. It may happen to use the same font as `\mathbf` but typically will not.