# operatorname vs text in subscripts

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, subscripts

I often see things like `\lambda_{\min}` or `\lambda_{\max}` in papers. To me, it seems that the "min" and "max" are not used as operators, but rather as text, so it would be better to do something like `\lambda_{\textup{min}}` or `\lambda_{\textup{max}}`.

However, while there's a [clear difference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname) between `\min` and `\textup{min}` in regular math mode, I haven't really been able to see a difference between how the different options are typset in the subscripts. Are there situations in which there is a difference?

Comment: they will use different fonts

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/691301/1090

Comment: that makes sense. What if it was mathrm instead of textup then?

Comment: then they are the same (usually)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you type `\lambda_{\min}` you get essentially the same as with `\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}`. They're different semantically: in the former case you're using an operator, in the latter case a textual subscripts.

You *may* get the same as `\mathrm` if you use `\textup`, but not necessarily: compare

```
$\lambda_{\textup{min}}$ and \textsf{$\lambda_{\textup{min}}$}
```

where the second “min” is typeset in the prevailing font valid outside the math formula. There wouldn't usually be differences with either `\mathrm{min}` or `\min`. Well, there *can* be!

Suppose you want to use a style that's unfortunately found in some publications, where sans serif type is used in some contexts, for instance tables. If you have math, you should define a suitable math version for sans serif type (look at `sansmath.sty` for an example). If the math version is correctly set up, then `\mathrm` would use the standard (upright) sans serif font.

Note also that, even without taking math versions into account, the font chosen by `\mathrm` may not be the same as the main text font, but I'd consider such cases as disputable, if not outright wrong, setting.

Barring such situations, using `\min` instead of `\mathrm{min}` for a textual subscript might be considered a venial sin against consistency in semantics, unless you consider this as a different way to write the result of applying the operator “min”.

You're the judge.